# chai-as-promised - doesn't seem to work with bluebird promises

Tags: bluebird, chai, chai-as-promised

I am trying to test a piece of code I wrote with bluebird promises, by using chai-as-promised.

My method to be tested returns a promise rejection, as follows:

```
  /**
   * Creates a new user entry in the database.
   * @param {JSONObject} userData -- User details for creation.
   * @return => {boolean} true if succefully created, false otherwise.
   **/
  createUser: function(userData) {
    return Promise.reject();
  },
```

The testing code is as this:

```
    describe('User creation test suite', function() {
        it('Should successfully create root user', function(done) {
            expect(users.createUser(sampleUsers.raam))
                .to.eventually.have.property('id').and.notify(done);
          //expect(Promise.resolve({foo:'bar'})).to.eventually.have.property('id').and.notify(done);
        });
```

Eventhough, the method is intentionally failing, but the testcase is being marked as passed.  Here is the output.

> User creation test suite
>
> ```
>   ✓ Should successfully create root user
> ```

If I test directly with a hardcoded string like

```
expect(Promise.resolve({foo:'bar'})).to.eventually.have.property('id').and.notify(done);
```

Then it seems to work.  What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
I found that it had nothing todo with bluebird promises or my method which is under test.  A simple hardcoded rejection also doesn't work correctly. That is...,

```
expect(Promise.reject({foo:'bar'})).to.eventually.have.property('id').and.notify(done)
```

returns as passed, instead of failing.  Am I doing something terribly wrong here?

Comment: I am using the following version of chai utils:  
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.2.0",
    "chai-http": "^2.0.1"
  },

Comment: After some more digging, I understand I am calling done without err.  How do I tell the done callback, that promise got rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Calling passing a callback to your Mocha test and then calling it when execution has finished -- as you are doing with the `done` callback -- is just one way to deal with [asynchronous code in Mocha](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code). Another is to simply return a promise from your test, which you can get from `chai-as-promised`. Try modifying you test like so:

```
it('Should successfully create root user', function() {
    return expect(users.createUser(sampleUsers.raam)).to.eventually.have.property('id');
});
```